# gsutil setmeta AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to change the cache control for my CDN by doing:

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control: max-age=0, s-maxage=86400" gs://<BUCKET>/*
```

However when I do I get the error: `AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden`

I've tried to change the ACL to a project but get the same error.

```
gsutil acl set -R public-read gs://<BUCKET>/
```

Ideally, I'd like this cache control to be on every bucket I create and have a default ACL to allow this.

Does anyone know how I can make this AccessDenied go away. I am signed into the owner of the project.

Comment: Signed in as the owner of the project where?  You need to make sure that whatever credentials you've configured for gsutil are a project owner.  Unfortunately, there's no way to set a default cache control for a bucket (but you can set a default object ACL).

Comment: @TravisHobrla So you're saying, whenever files are added, I then need to set cache-controls? I'm signed into the owner of the project via gcloud

Comment: You can't set cache-control by default at the bucket level.  However, you can set it when you create the object.  If you're logged in as project owner via gcloud, you should be able to access and modify your objects and buckets.  Feel free to send a debug log (gsutil -D your-command) to gs-team@google.com if you are certain that gsutil is acting as the project owner.

Comment: @TravisHobrla i created the bucket and uploaded files through the web interface. So i'm assuming that makes it a different owner?

Comment: Possibly - you can check the ACLs of the objects with the user that created them.

Comment: @TravisHobrla if I knew how to do that/know how to change them I probably wouldn't need this question haha. But I appreciate the insight. I shall research